# How do I restrict Internet access while still being able to make calls/receive messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, internet

Is there any way I can restrict my iphone from using the internet? Basically all apps should be blocked from using the internet, in one go, but I should still have the provision to make/receive phonecalls/messages.

Answer (score 5):

**Turn off Wi-Fi** (in Settings > Wi-Fi), and **turn off Mobile Data** (in Settings > General > Network).

This will keep the phone off the internet, but still allow phone calls and texts. (iMessage and MMS won't work, however).